# How to Fill Tab Item Area with WPF Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid, panel

How does one get a grid to fill the lower portion of a tab item and make is size correctly? (personally I would call that area the page). As it stands right now I have a grid at my layout root and then a tab control with several tabs on it. I have tried to drag and drop a grid onto the tab control; however, it it's always set to the fixed size that I initially created it for.

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,-1,0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1497*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="116*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="36*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="101*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="24*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="27*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="597*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="#FF080808" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Stroke="#FF0061FF" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
    <Image Source="LP_Script Logo_black.jpg" Margin="32,18,1206,27" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" MinWidth="250" MinHeight="56" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="ProgramSearchTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" KeyDown="ProgramSearchTextBox_KeyDown" PreviewKeyDown="ProgramSearchTextBox_PreviewKeyDown" Margin="2,1,2,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TabControl x:Name="mainMenuTabControl" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" PreviewKeyDown="mainMenuTabControl_PreviewKeyDown" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="-1,0,1,0" Grid.Row="3" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <TabItem x:Name="homeTab" Header="Home">
            <TabItem.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC1C0C0" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TabItem.Background>
            <DockPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" d:IsHidden="True">
                <Grid x:Name="dashboard" Background="#FFE5E5E5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="1636">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="fileMaintTab" Header="File Maintenance" KeyDown="fileMaintTab_KeyDown">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="336*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1316*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TreeView x:Name="FileMaintTreeView" Background="#FF747474" BorderThickness="1,1,5,1" BorderBrush="#FF0090FD" SelectedItemChanged="FileMaintTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,1,0">
                    <TreeView.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </TreeView.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: What i'm most concerned with is the filMaintTab.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example to demonstrate this for you:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Whole Row Tab">
            <Grid Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="I'm in the whole of this tab" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Half Row Tab">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Red">
                    <TextBlock Text="I'm in the bottom half of this tab" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Another Half Row Tab">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Red">
                    <TextBlock Text="I'm in the bottom half of this tab" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Varied Row Tab">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Green">
                    <TextBlock Text="I'm in the top quarter of this tab" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="3" Background="Green">
                    <TextBlock Text="I'm in the bottom quarter of this tab" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So in this instance there is a grid beneath the tab control, similar to what i'm currently doing. In this example though, what exactly is having a seemingly blank <RowDefinition /> accomplishing?

Comment: I added the `Another Half Row Tab` to show you what that does... `<RowDefinition />` is the same as `<RowDefinition Height="*" />`.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Grid` underneath your `TabItem`, try setting up your definitions, like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

For your `TreeView` definition, I changed it to the following:

```
<TreeView x:Name="FileMaintTreeView" Background="#FF747474" BorderBrush="#FF0090FD" SelectedItemChanged="FileMaintTreeView_SelectedItemChanged" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
```

(I removed things like margins and whatnot, you can put them back in if you want...

That will at least get your `TreeView` to fill up the entire `TabItem`.

If you wanted the `TabItem` to have something else on the page... let's say some control next to the `TreeView`, then you can add another `ColumnDefinition`. Width="*" means it will fill up the entire remaining space. Width="Auto" means it will only fill the size of the controls nested within that column/row.

Comment: This is for a grid panel. Removing the height and width of the actual grid just shrinks the grid panel into a dot in the middle of the tab page.

Comment: @user2859487 ok, my mistake, I misunderstood. I've updated my answer that can hopefully help you get started. When you drag and drop controls to the form, it sets things up for you automatically and I suspect that's what happened with your heights and widths for your row/column definitions. I prefer to just type up XAML by hand so you know exactly what you're getting.

Comment: Understandable. This is really close to what i'm looking for and i really appreciate the help; however, it's not filling out the entire page. i have the grid set up as you advised however, the grid leaves off a fair amount of space on both sides of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2859487 if you look at the definition of your tabcontrol (mainMenuTabControl) the columnspan is 3. That means it only takes up 3 columns of its parent grid. Setting it to 4 will help a little bit. However, I think the parent grid's rowdefinitions and columndefinitions might be screwed up also if you were just dragging things to the form and moving them around manually. You might want to apply the same concept from my answer to the parent grid. The parent grid I'm referring to is the very first grid definition (4 columns, 6 rows).

Comment: hmmm i'm stumped. The main issue is the fact that everything gets centered on the tab page portion regardless. i cannot get anything to anchor. if i put something next to the treeview, the grid will expand when the item is visible but the tree view i centered when i make it disappear.... would a dock panel be better for my current situation at the moment? or is there a way to bind the width of the grid to the position of desired row/columns?

Comment: @user2859487 if you were to put say a textbox next to the treeview, I would recommend making a second column in your grid definition (let's say with an Auto width). Then place the textbox in grid.column=1. You can set widths and heights on the textbox itself and watch the grid expand to the size it needs to contain the textbox. You can choose the type of panel that best suits your needs, but I've found that grids and stackpanels have been the most useful to me. I recommend checking out the following link for a very basic tutorial of how they work. http://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, finally I found reason from `TabControlStyle.xaml`(which is a style file), by adding following settings:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">

                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>

                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```